# vertically stacked monitors do not line up

Tags: display

I run my system with the big monitor stacked on top of the laptop monitor.  I can not align the monitors in the control panel so they are one on top of the other.  I can only join them at the corners. see image below. how do I align the screens so movement between windows is the same as the physical reality.

[image: screen shot of monitor alignment problem]

Answer (score -1):

Have you clicked and dragged them?

You could also try using another display management app if the stock one isn’t working. Also try an update

Comment: Yes I have clicked and dragged. It keeps jumping back to the layout in the picture I posted earlier. Also, I am current on all the updates but still no change.

I didn't realize there was another display management app. I thought we were restricted to the one in the control panel

Comment: if you type in display you should find some in the store